# How to edit a combobox dropdown item using API calles

Tags: api, combobox, vb6, sendmessage, listitem

I'm building my own combobox usercontrol in vb6 using api calles.. 
So i found most of the messages i need except for one.. No matter how much i search the internet i can't find a sendmessage call to edit a dropdown item..
There's a message to get an item text which is CB_GETLBTEXT .. But it seems that there's no   CB_SETLBTEXT

So how can i edit a dropdown item text

There's a work around for this by deleting the item then re-inserting it with the updated text but i don't really wish to do so.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

CBEM_GETEDITCONTROL Message

---

Retrieves the handle to the edit control portion of a ComboBoxEx control. A ComboBoxEx control uses an edit box when it is set to the CBS_DROPDOWN style.

Syntax

To send this message, call the SendMessage function as follows.

```
lResult = SendMessage(      // returns LRESULT in lResult     (HWND) 
hWndControl,      // handle to destination control     (UINT)
CBEM_GETEDITCONTROL,      // message ID     
(WPARAM) wParam,      // = 0; not used, must be zero    
(LPARAM) lParam      // = 0; not used, must be zero );
```

*From Help*.

> Edit Control Selection Fields
>
> **The selection field is the portion of a combo box that displays the currently selected list item. In simple and drop-down combo boxes, the selection field is an edit control and can be used to enter text that is not in the list.**
>
> An application can retrieve or set the contents of the selection field and can determine or set the edit selection. The application can also limit the amount of text a user can type in the selection field. When the contents of the selection field change, the system sends notification messages to the parent window or dialog box procedure.
>
> To retrieve the content of the selection field, an application can send the WM_GETTEXT message to the combo box. To set the contents of the selection field of a simple or drop-down combo box, an application can send the **WM_SETTEXT** message to the combo box.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question.. What i need is a message to set the text of an item in the dropdown list portion of the combo.. Not to set the text of the edit portion.